# Graphview horizontal labels not scrolling

Tags: android, label, android-graphview

I am working on project which requires **graph drawing**. I have used [this](http://android-graphview.org) Library. Its working perfectly only problem i am facing is that, the **horizontal labels** are not scrolling.This X-axis labels are always fixed. Whereas vertical labels are automatically adjusted when i zoom in and out.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the labels cannot scroll, but they can update to reflect the data in the current viewport; however, this cannot be done with a static horizontal label assignment. For example, the following will not work:

```
horizontalLables = new String[] {"Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"};
graphView.setHorizontalLabels(horizontalLables);
```

Instead, it is necessary to use a CustomLabelFormatter as follows:

```
graphView.setCustomLabelFormatter(new CustomLabelFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
        if (isValueX) {
            // Assuming only 7 total values here
            return horizontalLables[(int) value];
        } else
            return String.format("%.2f", value);
    }
});
```

You can then specify the amount of labels to show and allow scrolling as follows:

```
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(4);
graphView.setViewPort(0, 3);
graphView.setScrollable(true);
```

Hope that helps.